# jpa annotation error: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 entity (list) related to another entity with a code, how should I define the JPA annotation, if I want to save a list of ProductCharacteristic and ProductStatistic separately but have the same Product in the table?

Do I need to create a ProductCharacteristicTable entity that contains a Product and a List of ProductCharacteristic?

Presently, I have the following error: Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.xyz.ProductCharacteristic.product -> com.xyz.Product

or this error
caused by: javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    private String code;
}

@Entity
public class ProductCharacteristic {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade =  CascadeType.MERGE)
    private Product product;

    private String attributeCode;
    private String attributeValue;
}

@Entity
public class ProductStatistic {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade =  CascadeType.ALL)
    private Product product;

    private String attributeCode;
    private String attributeFormat;
    private String attributeValue;
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: you are attempting to persist some object(s) but haven't posted the code where you set the relationships and persist them. Consequently no comment is possible until you do

Comment: There is no magic that save the Product automaticly!  Do I only need to manually save the Product with the Product CrudRepository (spring-data)?